# how to change the sequence of y-axis in matlab

Tags: matlab

the command i wrote in the matlab command window is

```
X=[-1 -2 -3 -4 -5]; Y=[-4 -5 -8 -7 -6];A=[X;Y]';bar(A);
```

i want to reverse my figure i try the command:

```
>>axis ij
```

and also

```
>>set(h1, 'Ydir', 'reverse')
```

But it gaves to me a figure that y-axis start from (0 to -8)!
**I want the y-axis to start from (-8 to 0) and make bar command depending on these start.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
X = [-1 -2 -3 -4 -5]; Y = [-4 -5 -8 -7 -6]; A = [X;Y]'; %// data
bar(-A);
m = max(-A(:));
set(gca,'ytick',0:m); set(gca,'yticklabel',-m:0)
```

[image]

Comment: the y*axis is changed but the bar command results not change by the new y-axis scale

Comment: i don`t need to change y-axis only,i need to change also the bar command results example: x-axis value (1) should Corresponds to y-axis(-1,-4) not (-7,-4)